# Java name for getter that returns Boolean class according to naming convention

Tags: java, netbeans

I've noticed that for getters that return `Boolean` (not `boolean`!) netbeans generates getter with "get" prefix. For example:

```
private Boolean main;

public Boolean getMain(){
  return this.main;
}
```

Is this wrong (according to naming convention)? Or "is" prefix only for primitive type?

Comment: There's no right or wrong here. I think isMain or hasMain or supportsMain (depnding on what main means) are more descriptive. I don't think it should make a different whether it's boolean or Boolean.

Comment: Both "get" and "is" are accepted as prefixes, the "is" just makes it easier to spot that it returns a 'true' or 'false'. But, for Boolean, it could also return null, so maybe that's why the "get" was chosen over the "is" prefix

Comment: "Wrong" according to *what*?

Comment: @iJava it would help if you could clarify if you mean the JavaBeans naming convention - if you don't, then you can call the method whatever you like, and the question doesn't really make sense (or at least is primarily opinion-based). If you do, then it simplifies the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a quote from the actual [JavaBeans specification document](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/):

> **8.3.2 Boolean properties**
>
> In addition, for boolean properties, we allow a getter method to match the pattern:
>
> `public boolean is<PropertyName>();`
>
> This `is<PropertyName>` method may be provided instead of a `get<PropertyName>` method, or it may be provided in addition to a `get<PropertyName>` method. In either case, if the `is<PropertyName>` method is present for a boolean property then we will use the `is<PropertyName>` method to read the property value.

Note that this applies to `boolean` and not `Boolean` values. Also note that `is` is an *allowed alternative* to `get` and `get` is *always appropriate*.

Comment: The OP hasn't mentioned JavaBeans and as far as I can tell NetBeans *generate getters* doesn't necessarily have to do with JavaBeans either. Sure, it's not wrong to use *get* but I'd say it's a bit inaccurate to pass the JavaBeans spec as a general convention in this case.

Comment: I don't think the question would have any weight if it were not asking about the JavaBeans naming convention. It would amount to a *primarily opinion-based* question.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the main point of generating getters is interop with introspective libraries which *invariably* assume the JavaBeans convention.

Comment: I disagree. I've used getter/setter of selected properties an uncountable number of times and I've never used JavaBeans. (I had to read up on the details of JavaBeans just for this discussion.)

Comment: It is fully possible that you have never worked with Spring, Hibernate, Jackson, or any other of a huge number of libraries relying on JavaBeans---but most Java users do, so I think my comment is still valid when applied to the Java community as a whole.

Comment: Don't forget JSP, IDEs in general, etc. I think it's safe to assume that since the *only* relevant naming convention here is JavaBeans and that the OP specifically mentioned "naming convention", then that's what the question is about, even if the OP doesn't realize that it's JavaBeans defining the convention. FWIW, java itself doesn't have a concept of a "property" - that's a JavaBeans concept, so @aioobe the fact you say you've used properties with getters/setters probably means you've been using JavaBeans all along and just not calling it that.

Comment: @CupawnTae, (A) I don't see how "IDEs in general" rely on JavaBeans in any way. (B) I don't think the interpretation of *"naming convention"* automatically should default to that of JavaBeans. Trust me, it's *not* the only relevant Java naming convention. (C) I guarantee you that I've never relied on JavaBean conventions in my code. In fact I (and many with me) consider [it to be an anti pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model). (D) assuming the term "property" is bound to JavaBeans is [wrong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/information/glossary.html#property).

Comment: That "anemic domain model" is a quite misplaced critique and here's why: most business functions are not coupled to just one piece of data: the data objects do not naturally *own* those pieces of logic. Java and most other "OOP" languages being single-dispatch, this naturally leads to the split between code and data.

Comment: Plus, "anemic domain model" has nothing to do with JavaBeans, anyway, since JavaBeans is just a Java-specific convention to raise object properties to an equal footing with methods. In most other cases this is integrated into the language itself: just the property declaration gives the object both the instance variable and the accessor methods.

Comment: @aioobe I meant IDEs in general follow JavaBeans conventions when generating getters/setters. JavaBeans introduced the concept of properties to Java, I remember when it happened. If you're talking about Java properties, you're talking about JavaBeans-style properties. When Oracle say "property" that's what they mean https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html. If you have an example of a Java naming convention relevant to getters/setters that contradicts JavaBeans, I'd be interested to see it.

Answer (score 6):

Netbeans is not wrong here - for `Boolean` *object* properties `get` is correct. For one thing the property value could be `null`, in which case `is` wouldn't make sense.

The [javabeans spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) allows `is` for type `boolean` as a special case, and *does not mention* `Boolean`. To assume that this special case extends to `Boolean` objects would be invalid.

Comment: That completely depends on the situation. Note that in this case the main is *private* which means that there could very well be class invariants in place guaranteeing that main is never null, OR, a null value may internally represent false.

Comment: I'm just saying that there are a lot of assumptions in your answer and you seem to argue that one is correct while the other isn't.

Comment: Also, trying to remember the circumstances recently - think it was jax-ws `wsimport` - generates `boolean` and `is` for a mandatory field, and `Boolean` and `get` for an optional one.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if the class containing the method is to be treated as a JavaBean or not.

If you intend it to be a JavaBean, then [Marko Topolnik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28450498/276052) is accurate.

Otherwise there's no right or wrong. Whether `get` or `is` (or something else) should be used depends on the contract and purpose of the method. Eran's first comment is spot on:

> There's no right or wrong here. I think isMain or hasMain or supportsMain (depnding on what main means) are more descriptive. I don't think it should make a different whether it's boolean or Boolean.

You ask what the convention is, and I'd say that the convention is to name the method as descriptive and semantically accurate as possible.

To elaborate on *is* vs *get*:

- If the method is intended as a general accessor for a capital-B `Boolean` property that make take on the value `null` it makes more sense to use `get`.
- If the method is intended to give the status of an otherwise internal (as in this case `private`) non-null flag, I would argue that `is` would be an appropriate prefix. (Although I would probably use `boolean` as return value, unless there was a common use case to do for instance `isMain().hashCode()` or something similar.)

Answer (score 0):

On `Boolean` object you can apply many methods: `toString`, `equals`, `valueOf`..

There's no complete answer for your question, it really depends on the usage and who calls the method. It make sense to have:

```
public boolean isMain(){
    return this.main.booleanValue();
}
```

But if your logic doesn't insure that `main` can have `null` value, then `get` is a good prefix.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct . Boolean is a wrapper class of the primitive data type boolean . So Boolean will return object. Same `get` is used for object also like primitive data type.

Answer (score 0):

According to OCP Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 8 Programmer II Study Guide book:

Which of the following could be correctly included in a JavaBean?

```
public boolean isPlaying() { return playing; }
public boolean getPlaying() { return playing; }
public Boolean isDancing() { return dancing; }
```

The first line is correct because it defines a proper getter for a boolean variable.
The second example is also correct, since boolean may use is or get. **The third line is
incorrect, because a Boolean wrapper should start with get, since it is an object.**